# How to keep signature of a callable argument visible in a C++ template?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, template-argument-deduction

The function `f()` below takes the callable argument `fc` whose signature is nicely visible in the function definition.

```
// scaffolding for function definition
template<typename T>
struct Identity {   
    using type = T;
};

// still scaffolding for function definition  
template<typename T>
using Make_deducible = typename Identity<T>::type;  

// function definiton
template <typename T>
T f(T val, Make_deducible<std::function<T(T)>> fc) // we see fc's expected signature
{ return fc(val); }
```

Note that it can be called in all the following ways:

```
int g(int i) { return i * i; };
f(5, g); // call with function ptr: rarely used

std::function<int(int)> fo{[](int i){ return i * i; }};
f(6, fo); // call with std::function object: tedious

f(7, [](int i){ return i * i; }); // call with lambda closure: usual use case
```

What bothers me is that the definition of `f()` requires some scaffolding to work. So, my questions is:

Is there a **less** roundabout way of doing this **while** keeping the signature of `get_val` **visible** in definition, and **still** have the function be callable with a lambda?

Comment: Make deducible blocks deduction.  That seems like a poor choice of names.  Or a serious misunderstanding.  Maybe both.

Comment: Couldn't you just use `std::common_type_t<std::function<T(T))>` ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  You function can be as simple as `template <typename T, typename Func> T f(T val, Func f) { reutrn f(val); }`.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I don't see the expected signature of `f` in that way.

Comment: @Yakk : You are probably right. Obviously I am not well versed in templates. Naming it that way came about after the fact that, without it, I get the compiler error saying something like "could not deduce template argument from lambda". I just made the pain go away.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the callable is convertible to `std::function<T(T)>`:

```
template<class T, class F>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<F, std::function<T(T)>>::value, T>
f(T v, F fn) {
    return fn(v);
}
```

Comment: Ckever truck for callability.  Note that in other contexts, void return type gives various results depending on compiler and version here. In  c++11 this does not work at all of course.

Comment: @Yakk Thank you. It is OP's original idea, i only made it work.

Answer (score -1):

Make deducible blocks the compiler from trying tomdeduce that argument.  Which seems like a poor choice of name; that is usually called `block_deduction` or something.

The easiest way to include the signature is a comment:

```
template <class T, class F /*T(T) signature*/>
T f(T val, F fc)
{ return fc(val); }
```

wherever you want it.

If we want compiler enforcing, we can block deduction and type erase like you did in your question.  Another choice:

```
template<class Sig, class F, class=void>
struct can_call:std::false_type{};
template<class R, class...Args, class F>
struct can_call<R(Args...),F,std::enable_if_t<
  std::is_convertible<std::result_of_t<F(Args...)>,R>{}
>>:std::true_type{};
template<class...Args, class F>
struct can_call<void(Args...),F,std::void_t<
  std::result_of_t<F(Args...)>,R>{}
>>:std::true_type{};
```

that defines `can_call<Sig, F>` which is true if and only if you can call F in a context compatible with `Sig`.

```
template <class T, class F /*T(T) signature*/>
std::enable_if_t<can_call<T(T),F&>{}, T> T f(T val, F fc)
{ return fc(val); }
```

and now `F` is checked at overload resolution time to ensure it is compatible.

I used some C++14 and C++17 `std::void_t`.  `void_t` is easy to write in C++11, and easy to find on SO.

There may be typos; on phone.